# SCHEME: Remove sub-lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I haven't had any luck creating function that removes sublists.

I have this list:

```
'((("a" "c") ("a" "l")) (("b" "c") ("b" "l")) (("c" "hmm")))
```

This should be result:

```
'(("a" "c") ("a" "l") ("b" "c") ("b" "l") ("c" "hmm"))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show us what you have done so far, especially since this is homework.

Comment: Follow the design recipe: Do you have a data definition? A purpose statement? Test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used two functions flatten (found on the net) and createPairs.

First function flattens list to 1 level deep list like this:

```
'("a" "c" "a" "l" "b" "c" "b" "l" "c" "hmm")
```

And second function createPairs joins list by pairs like this:

```
'(("a" "c") ("a" "l") ("b" "c") ("b" "l") ("c" "hmm"))
```

Here are the used functions:

Flatten:

```
 (define (flatten list)
   (cond ((null? list) '())
         ((list? (car list)) (append (flatten (car list)) (flatten (cdr list))))
         (else
          (cons (car list) (flatten (cdr list))))))
```

CreatePairs:

```
(define (createPairs a)
  (cond ((null? a) '()) 
        (else 
         (cons (list (car a) (car (cdr a)))
               (createPairs (cdr (cdr a)))))))
```